# put some function in cloud and execute from any place cellular phone or tablet or laptop

Tags: cloud-deploy

Mostly I would like to have back a small string produced after entering few integers...

anyway the functions is:

```
pw[j_Integer, nd_Integer, sl_Integer, oeo_Integer] := 
 Style[StringJoin[" ", 
   Map[ctec[[# + 1]] &, 
    First[RealDigits[N[1/Prime[j*sl + oeo], (j*sl + oeo)*10*5], 
      Length[ctec], nd, -sl*oeo]]], " "], FontSize -> 25, 
  FontColor -> Red, Bold, Background -> Yellow]
```

where ctec is a list of all key-able characters in Latin-kb